# Linux Return code not working properly when running script

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following script written in linux bash to check if file exists and I can read its contents. When run manually its working. But when I run the script, return code is blank.

`${PARAM_FILES_ARR[@]}` has values like /somedir/file1.prm, /somedir/files2.prm etc.

Edit: As per comments I am adding assignment of `${PARAM_FILES_ARR[@]}` as follows.

cdoe written below. Plesae help.

```
#!/bin/bash
...some code...
#The array gets assigned as below from a file in the same script
PARAM_FILES_ARR=($(cat $PARAM_FILES_LIST | sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' | sed '/^[#]/d' | sed '/^[$]{2}/d' | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//' | sed 's/\\/\//g' | envsubst))

for FNAME in "${PARAM_FILES_ARR[@]}"
    do
        cat "${FNAME}" > /dev/null 2>&1
        RETURN_CODE_FILE=$?
        if [ "${RETURN_CODE_FILE}" -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Warning! Could not Read PARAM FILE ${FNAME}"
            echo "${RETURN_CODE_FILE}"
        fi
    done
```

Comment: Do you set PARAM_FILES_ARR externally?  Why don't you use a regular test `[ -r "$FNAME" ]`?

Comment: I don't see that you would actually set `PARAM_FILES_ARR`. If you don't set it, it would have to be an environment variable, **but** you use the variable as an array, and environment variables are not arrays, but simple strings. Also, I don't understand the purpose of the `cat` command.

Comment: @user1934428 Sorry forgot to add it question. Just Edited the question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Simplify

```
for fname; do
    if [[ -r $fname ]]; then
        echo "$fname readable"
    else
        echo "$fname unreadable"
    fi
done
```

##### Usage

```
./script <*files> or <bash array>
```

##### To go deeper

- to parse arguments, `for fname` is sufficient
- [Don't use UPPER case variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)
- `[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals. Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, I recommend `[[`

Answer (score -1):

Your script don't see an array with files as Allan Wind suggested in comments. Try to change it like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
for FNAME in "$@"
    do
    ...
```

And run like this:

```
./script_name "${PARAM_FILES_ARR[@]}"
```

Comment: No need `$@`, check my answer ;)

Comment: @GillesQuenot I've checked your answer 5 edits back ;)
You're right `$@` could be omitted, but I left it to make answer more similar to OP's style.
And it's more readable this way(IMHO).